# Get specific value from an object and push it into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Hello I have an obj(came from JSON parsed) and I'm trying to get only one value from it the "VALUE"(default.timelineData)

for example from this obj I want an array [38,35,87,63,34].

I tried with Object.values and also to pass it to an array and then work with it but it's very complicated and I believe there is a shortcut to it.  function without success hopes for help thanks...

```js
{
   "default":{
      "timelineData":[
         {
            "time":"1610323200",
            "formattedTime":"Jan 11, 2021",
            "formattedAxisTime":"Jan 11",
            "value":[
               38
            ],
            "hasData":[
               true
            ],
            "formattedValue":[
               "38"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time":"1610409600",
            "formattedTime":"Jan 12, 2021",
            "formattedAxisTime":"Jan 12",
            "value":[
               35
            ],
            "hasData":[
               true
            ],
            "formattedValue":[
               "35"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time":"1610496000",
            "formattedTime":"Jan 13, 2021",
            "formattedAxisTime":"Jan 13",
            "value":[
               87
            ],
            "hasData":[
               true
            ],
            "formattedValue":[
               "87"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time":"1610582400",
            "formattedTime":"Jan 14, 2021",
            "formattedAxisTime":"Jan 14",
            "value":[
               63
            ],
            "hasData":[
               true
            ],
            "formattedValue":[
               "63"
            ]
         },
         {
            "time":"1610668800",
            "formattedTime":"Jan 15, 2021",
            "formattedAxisTime":"Jan 15",
            "value":[
               34
            ],
            "hasData":[
               true
            ],
            "formattedValue":[
               "34"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "averages":[
         
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: please add your try. maybe a look to [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) would help a bit.

Answer (score -1):

The property you are trying to access is an `Array`. You can use `Array.map` to iterate through the elements and push the returned values into a new array at the same time. Like this:

```js
const values = obj.default.timelineData.map(item => item.value[0])
console.log(values); // [38, 35, 87, 63, 34]
```

Comment: Perhaps better would be to `flatMap` the arrays of arrays and include all from each level in the results, and not just the first one.  (I know there is only one in each now, but who knows whether/when that might change?)